# SSH with MAC based filtering using iptables - recommended?

Tags: ssh, security, iptables, mac-address

I have a server in an internal network (login there via VPN) from where I login to the server via SSH with OpenSSH public/private key authentication. From a security point of view, I want to tie the MAC addresses of my three used clients via `iptables` on the server so that only these clients can login with it.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP
```

However, is it recommended though to do it this way? What other (better) methods can I use to tie the SSH login to the used clients?

(If someone wants to request 2FA, unfortunately 2FA is not possible as potential solution.)

Thanks.

Comment: Might be related on our Security SE: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/154076/82570

Comment: What layer does the VPN work on? Is at a level 2 (so carrying MAC addresses).?

Comment: No, it's a complete a waste of time. Everybody can change their MAC address. That's not any "security" whatsoever.

Comment: @mosvy any recommendations then?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not any security whatsoever... or wouldn't be if this server was internet facing. It will, at the very least, protect against the vast majority of attempts to probe the server by bots. I do the same thing using ipsets and knockd. It's certainly not sufficient security. But paired with strong preshared keys it should be relatively solid.

Comment: You could implement a poor man's two-factor simply be re-enabling password login while leaving the preshared keys enabled. Then someone would need both a valid password _and_ preshared ssl keys. There's a _lot_ that can be done to harden ssh: https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/openssh.html

Comment: As mosvy has said, impersonating MAC addresses is really easy. To answer these kinds of questions, you need to add enough information so we can establish a **threat model**: What kind of malicious uses are you trying to protect against? "I just want it to be secure" is no threat model. E.g. if you trust everyone on the internal network, and nobody untrusted can connect to the internal network, the situation is very much different compared to "anyone with a LAN cable and a laptop can connect".

Comment: I would like to avoid the scenario that if the private keys have been shared with someone else, the untrusted internal person shall not log in to the server. Therefore I thought that binding it to another client-based information such as the MAC address could be an idea to prevent it. Any suggestions are welcome. Binding to an IP address will be difficult as these may change (DHCP).

Comment: @Ferit If people lose/share their private keys, the only way to secure them is to only use keys with passwords.

Comment: @M_dk Sadly, users can remove password protection of their keys by setting a blank new password via `$ ssh-keygen -p -f ssh_identity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am supposing that you want to prevent your SSH server from accepting connections from untrusted hosts even though they supply valid user credentials. Is it right?

A possible solution to tie users' public key authentication to selected client hosts is via host-based authentication. By setting up host-based authentication and defining `AuthenticationMethods` parameter in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to either:

```
AuthenticationMethods hostbased,publickey hostbased,keyboard-interactive hostbased,password
```

Or:

```
AuthenticationMethods hostbased,publickey
```

That will instruct SSH daemon to request clients to authenticate the hosts they are connecting from before checking users' keys or passwords. The former alternative allows password-based authentication, while the latter restricts it to public keys only. Since host-based authentication is based on keypairs, SSH server will be able to authenticate clients with dynamic IP addresses.

---

Here follows complete instructions. The documentation of how SSH performs host-based authentication is written in [`ssh(1)` man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh). Please note how SSH identifies users and check whether it is applicable to your case.

> Host-based authentication works as follows: If the machine the user logs in from is listed in `/etc/hosts.equiv` or `/etc/ssh/shosts.equiv` on the remote machine, and **the user names are the same on both sides**, or if the files `~/.rhosts` or `~/.shosts` exist in the user's home directory on the remote machine and **contain a line containing the name of the client machine and the name of the user on that machine**, the user is considered for login. Additionally, the server must be able to verify the client's host key for login to be permitted. This authentication method closes security holes due to IP spoofing, DNS spoofing, and routing spoofing. [Note to the administrator: `/etc/hosts.equiv`, `~/.rhosts`, and the rlogin/rsh protocol in general, are inherently insecure and should be disabled if security is desired.]

To enable host-based authentication in OpenSSH:

- Set the following parameter values in [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config

HostbasedAuthentication yes
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
IgnoreRhosts yes

# AuthenticationMethods hostbased,publickey hostbased,keyboard-interactive hostbased,password
AuthenticationMethods hostbased,publickey
```

- To perform host-based authentication, you can trust the hostname information supplied by clients by setting `HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly yes` in [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config

HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly yes
```

- Or, alternatively, you can configure SSH daemon to identify hostnames via resolution of clients' IP addresses using information stored in either `/etc/hosts` file or PTR records in network's DNS server:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config

HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly no
UseDNS yes
```

- List the hostnames of the authorized clients in `/etc/ssh/shosts.equiv` file. Create it manually if it doesn't exist. The syntax of the file is almost the same as documented in [man host.equiv(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.equiv), however [SSH daemon does not accept empty hostnames](https://github.com/openssh/libopenssh/blob/05dfdd5f54d9a1bae5544141a7ee65baa3313ecd/ssh/auth-rhosts.c#L138).

```
# /etc/ssh/shosts.equiv

ssh-client-alpha
ssh-client-bravo
ssh-client-charlie
```

- List the public keys of the authorized hosts in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file. A convenient way to do so is via [`ssh-keyscan`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keyscan):

```
[root@ssh-server ~]# ssh-keyscan ssh-client-alpha >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
[root@ssh-server ~]# ssh-keyscan ssh-client-bravo >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
[root@ssh-server ~]# ssh-keyscan ssh-client-charlie >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

After configuring OpenSSH server to accept host-based authentication requests, clients must also be configured to request host-based authentication:

- Set the following parameter values in [`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config):

```
# /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Host *
    HostbasedAuthentication yes
    EnableSSHKeySign yes
```

- Ensure that SUID/SGID bits in [`ssh-keysign`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ssh-keysign) executable grant read permission to host's private key files:

```
[root@ssh-client-alpha ~]# find /usr -name ssh-keysign -ls
 16517300    616 -r-xr-sr-x   1  root     ssh_keys   630344 Feb  4 16:01 /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign

[root@ssh-client-alpha ~]# ls -l /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*key
-rw-r----- 1 root ssh_keys  480 Apr 13 06:51 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r----- 1 root ssh_keys  387 Apr 13 06:51 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r----- 1 root ssh_keys 2578 Apr 13 06:51 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```